# Why not use 'ja' in the favicon?

Tags: discussion

Isn't the language code for Japanese JA?  So, in the drop-down menu, info from Japanese Exchange comes up with a little icon that says "JP".  What's that all about?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why it says JP.

Both JA and JP are fairly common abbreviations.  Officially, [JA is the ISO 639-1 language code for Japanese](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php), while [JP is the ISO 3166-1 country code for Japan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#JP).  I think both are understandable, and obviously Japan and Japanese are very closely associated, but since the site is about the *Japanese language* and not the *country of Japan* it might make sense to use JA instead.

Comment: Well, I know when I'm programming, I've always got to use JA. :/

Answer (score 6):

Darius Jahandarie wrote [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17574542#17574542):

> I wanted to say that "JP" is a far more common abbreviation for anything related to Japan than "JA". Only computer programmers know about "JA".

So this would be an argument to stick with JP.

Comment: I'm posting this for him since he's having trouble accessing meta right now.

Comment: Shut up.  Lol.  Go JA.